# Visual Studio Node.js Express 4 Application Server Quits

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017

Googling didn't get me vary far with this so I wanted to make a post about it.

In Visual Studio 2017 if you create a new Node.js Express 4 Application project, build it and debug it then the Node.js server will just crash and exit before you can read any output from the CMD window that it was running in.

Checking the log file `C:\Users\matt\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-node-debug2.txt` yielded no usable information for me. What was causing it to crash and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be sure you update your npm packages in Visual Studio by performing the following steps.

1. In solution explorer, expand the npm node.
   [image: Solution Explorer]
2. Right click and choose the appropriate option.
   a. Install Missing npm Packages
   b. Update npm Packages
   [image: NPM Packages]

That didn't fix the issue but it doesn't hurt. Now if you rebuild your project and debug it by pressing `ctrl + F5` then it will pause on the error that is causing the Node.js server to crash.

[image: Node.js Server Error]

So, The server is having trouble binding to port `1337`. I'm assuming that's because it's such a low port number and we're running Visual Studio as a regular user and not as an administrator. To change the port number to a higher value you can edit the `app.js` file in Visual Studio.

I Changed the following line
[image: Setting the Port 1]
to
[image: Setting the Port 2]

Now, if you save everything, rebuild the project and debug it by clicking the debug button or pressing `F5` the server will successfully start. The browser will still be directed to port `1337` instead of port `65073` though. After changing the port number in the address in the browser the page loads fine.

I'm not sure how make it open to the port we set. I'll update this post if I figure that part out.

Comment: For those who come across this in the future, instead of changing the process.env.PORT value, you just need to change the NodeExpress Debug Properties, which has an Application Port field.